# Learning to use React but I'm stumped on how to incorporate promises

Tags: jquery, reactjs, redux, promise

I understand how promises work and have used JQuery in the past to do promises. I am building a really simple application that uses the YouTube API to show videos. I have run into a brick wall because I encountered a situation where I need to use a promise but don't know how.

In my index.js file I define an App class who's constructor makes a call to the API for a list of videos matching the default search term "national geographic." Once those results come back (need to use a promise here) I want to make a call to this.setSelectedVideo to get the specific video to play.

```
//  Node Modules
import React        from 'react';
import ReactDOM     from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch     from 'youtube-api-search';

//  Components
import SearchBar    from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList    from './components/video_list';
import VideoDetail  from './components/video_detail';

const API_KEY_YOUTUBE = <MY_YOUTUBE_API_KEY>;

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            videos: [],
            selectedVideo: null
        };

        //  initialize videos: finish this up when you learn how to do redux promises
        this.videoSearch('National Geographic');
        this.setSelectedVideo(this.state.videos[0]);
    }

    videoSearch(term) {
        //  Make AJAX request to YouTube for a list of videos matching term.
        YTSearch({ key: API_KEY_YOUTUBE, term: term }, videos => {
            this.setState({ videos: videos });
        });
    }

    setSelectedVideo(video) {
        //  Make AJAX request to YouTube for the specific video being played.
        console.log(video);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row margin-bottom-md">
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <SearchBar onSearchTrigger={ term => this.videoSearch(term) } />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row margin-bottom-md">
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-8">
                        <VideoDetail video={ this.state.selectedVideo } />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-12 col-lg-4">
                        <VideoList 
                            videos={ this.state.videos }
                            onVideoSelect={ selectedVideo => this.setSelectedVideo({ selectedVideo }) }
                            selectedVideo={ this.state.selectedVideo }
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}   //  App class end

//  Take this component's generated HTML and put it on the page.
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#react-render'));
```

I've been looking around online and have heard a few options.
1. I can use vanilla JS promise.
2. I can somehow incorporate JQuery into my application and use its promise function. Unfortunately it sounds like I need to include a separate package manager from NPM to do this?
3. I heard that redux has a promise function.

Which of these three options is the best / what is the simplest way for me to implement a simple promise here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do what you ask for:

```
videoSearch(term) {
    //  Make AJAX request to YouTube for a list of videos matching term.
    YTSearch({ key: API_KEY_YOUTUBE, term: term }, videos => {
        this.setState({ 
            videos: videos,
            selectedVideo: videos[0]
        });
    });
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/@charlie.spencer/making-requests-to-the-youtube-api-with-react-fbd50fa8d77e

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [redux-api-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-api-middleware). 
Since you are managing your application with a state container (redux), it would be a good practice to make http requests with redux kind of flow style: dispatch action which will in turn make the actual http call and then, call a predefined reducer accordingly.

So it would look something like this:

// actions_file.js

```
import { RSAA } from `redux-api-middleware`;

// the action itself
export function myYoutubeAction(someArg) {
  return {
      [RSAA]: {
        endpoint: '<YOUTUBE_API_PATH>',
        method: 'GET',
        types: ['REQUEST_REDUCER', 'SUCCESS_REDUCER', 'FAILURE_REDUCER']
      }
}
```

// reducer_file.js

```
  // this reducers is called right after http request made
  'REQUEST_REDUCER': (state, action) {
    const { response } = action.payload;
    ...
    ...
    // DO SOME STUFF AND UPDATE STATE..
  }

  // this reducers is called right after http request is back
  'SUCCESS_REDUCER': (state, action) {
    const { response } = action.payload;
    ...
    ...
    // DO SOME STUFF WITH RESPONSE AND UPDATE STATE..
  }
```

Of course you can use native (or external) http request libraries (request-promise, fetch), make an inline http request (and bypass the redux flow) and it'll work fine as well, but I think it would be more messy and less clean to do so in your case (when using a state container). Take advantage over the redux flow and let the http request go through the redux circle: **dispatch action** (eg. http request) -> **change state** in reducer (after request, succeed or failure) -> **update UI**

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on your situation, but as nearly [10% of all current users](https://caniuse.com/#search=Promises) do not use a browser that supports native Promises (IE), I would recommend using an external library.

I have been using [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com) for quite some time and I would recommend it, but a lot of alternatives are available.

I would advise against including jQuery only for it’s promise capabilities as it will take a lot of unnecessary bandwidth for your users while the rest of the library is being unused.